# Imitating a phone call?

Tags: effects, audio-recording

I was wondering if there was an easy way to do a voice over of a phone call with it actually sounding like someone on the phone instead of just a voice over?

Comment: Convert the audio track to 32kbps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Downsampling it to 8KHz will get you most of the way toward that telephone sound.

[**Here’s a demo.**](http://external.sidneysm.com/8khz-demo.mp3)

Then, to get even closer, use a band pass filter to knock out everything below about 500Hz and above 2000Hz (you can find an example of using Audacity’s equalizer to do this [here](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=5081)).

[**Here’s a demo with the full effect.**](http://external.sidneysm.com/telephone-demo.mp3) (Same recording, I didn’t feel like making a second, more-descriptive one. :-) )

(For whatever reason, my copy of Chrome glitches a bit while playing these back. Not sure why. Other programs handle them fine.)

Comment: As well as bandlimiting and sharply filtering above and below the aforementioned frequencies, applying some judicious parallel compression and distortion will also help you achieve a more realistic result. Old handsets used carbon mics with notoriously lo-fi reproduction characteristics; whilst most phones now use tiny electrets the circuitry's designed to rapidly and severely compress (in terms of dynamic range) incoming sound with a long release. That's why if your conversational partner blows down the mic, everything goes silent momentarily then ramps back up. Compress the hell out of it!

Comment: the 2nd demo has no audible audio

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum: Still there for me. What are you using to listen to it?

Comment: its back up. It wasn't playing last time when the first demo did. don't know why